# Django WSGI segfaults when importing setproctitle module

Tags: apache-2.2, python, django, process, mod-wsgi

I want to use the [python setproctitle](http://code.google.com/p/py-setproctitle/) module to update the process name of a python WSGI worker process when it starts working on a request. (This is to try to track down what URLs are using all the CPU). I have written a simple Django middleware class that will call `setproctitle.setproctitle(request.path)`. This works fine in the django debug server (i.e. `python manage.py runserver`), i.e. I can see the request URL in the output of `top`.

However when I try to run the same code using apache & mod_wsgi the wsgi process segfaults when it loads the middleware python file. It segfaults at the `import setproctitle` line. (print statements before that line are executed, but not after).

Is it possible to get setproctitle working with wsgi?

The server is Ubuntu Linux, using apache, mod_wsgi, and django.

Answer (score 2):

Use gdb to work out why it crashes. See:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Debugging_Crashes_With_GDB

If that doesn't help you to work out problem yourself, then suggest you post all the details to the mod_wsgi mailing list as this site doesn't work well when needing to iteratively debug a problem.

Also try forcing use of main Python interpreter using:

```
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

It may be the case that setproctitle module doesn't work properly in sub interpreters, although I can't see why it wouldn't as it should just be a wrapper for a single function and should be pretty simple.